# Shadow dom parts not working with Child combinator

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, shadow-dom

*.html*

```
<ion-select
          mode="md"
          formControlName="sortBy"
          interface="popover"
          legacy="true"
          class="my-class"
            >
          <ion-select-option value="1">Newest</ion-select-option>

          <ion-select-option value="5">Price (High to Low)</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
```

.css

```
.my-class>ion-select::part(icon) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Can you tell me why the above is not working? But this works:

```
ion-select::part(icon) {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

I need to add the `my-class` dynamically here. That is why I need this.

[image]

Comment: if you write  ".my-class > ion-select"  you are saying to select any ion-select element that is a direct descendant of an element w/ the class 'my-class'. Looking at your markup, you do not have elements that fit the definition. The ion-select element that is visible in your example is not a descandant of my-class, it IS my class. So you could just write "ion-select.my-class::part(icon)" to do what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: @diopside This is working fine. Please put it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `>` selector, by which you are saying that `ion-select` needs  to be a direct child of `.my-class`.
This is not the case, looking at the HTML structure

Please use `ion-select.my-class::part(icon)`